# For Flash and SSD - what is the definition of Valid Page Count?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, flash, openvms

I have looked for hours to find a definition for Valid Page Count and have been unsuccessful. 
Can someone give me the definition of a Valid Page Count (VPC)?

Comment: The [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Valid+Page+Count) result mentioning [OpenVMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) is actually a red herring. The book just happens to have the words `count`, `valid` and `page` in close enough proximity to trigger the algorithm.

Comment: What research have you found so far?

Comment: Hi Burgi - I have scoured all of my company documents and tried in every way to find the definition on the internet. It's frustrating because it seems to be self-explanatory 'Valid Page Count'. A count of all the valid pages. But, what I do not understand is what makes a page 'valid'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing and Erasing NAND

Before we can understand the various maintenance algorithms that the controller employs to keep your SSD neat and tidy, we need to understand a few basics about how we read and write data to a NAND chip. Data is stored in a unit called a “page,”

excerpt from: http://web.stanford.edu/~rajivag/papers/wa_paper.pdf

Whereas the reclaiming policy that selects the blocks to garbage-collect is usually
based only on the amount of free space to be gained, the policy
defined in [2] also included the time elapsed since the last
writing of the block with data. In general, the objective is to
minimize the **number of valid pages** in the blocks selected for garbage collection, thereby minimizing the number of read
and write operations resulting from garbage collection.

From what I can understand a valid page is a page NOT marked for deletion in an SSD block.  Everything I have read says that SSD "garbage collection" is what is keeping a count on this, in order to make the SSD efficient as possible for future writes to the SSD.  I would guess that "number of valid pages" is what you are calling a valid page count.

Comment: Musselman - @musselman - thank you so much for your input. I did not realize that a data unit is also a page. So, (I think) after garbage collection, the valid page count is the count of usable pages that can receive data. I should have added in my original question that I am a technical writer. So, what you brainiac-engineers learned in your first year of college, I struggle with. Often times it is because I lack the understanding of the elementary elements - like 'a data is stored in units called pages'. - thanks again.